# What's the best practice to send a simply HTTP request and get its response with Akka?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I tried to code like this:

```
val requestUri : Uri = baseUri.withQuery(Uri.Query("aid" -> av))//av is a query parameter
val responseFuture: Future[HttpResponse] =
Http(system).singleRequest(HttpRequest(GET, uri = requestUri))
val response = Await.result(responseFuture, Duration.Inf)
```

I think I get the correct response, but how can I get the content of the response? What's the best practice to do that? Is it right to use `Future` like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general it is poor form to use `Await` on a `Future`.  It is usually unnecessary but "feels" like the correct method if you are unfamiliar with Futures.

Once a result comes as a Future you can leave the computation "inside" of the Future and add more functionality on top of the original value.

Addressing your question directly, you can use Future operators instead of Await to "get the content of the response" (see Frederic A.'s answer on why you should consider streams before going with the below solution) :

```
import scala.concurrent.duration._

val responseFuture : Future[HttpResponse] = ??? //same as in question

val responseBody : Future[ByteString] = 
  responseFuture
    .map(_.entity) 
    .flatMap(_.toStrict(10 seconds))
    .map(_.data)
```

This series of operations can also be accomplished using for comprehensions:

```
val responseBody : Future[ByteString] = 
  for {
    entity <- responseFuture.entity
    strict <- entity.toStrict(10 seconds)
    body   <- strict.data
  } yield body
```

If you want to print out the result when it is ready then you can do something like:

```
responseBody foreach { body =>
  println s"body: ${body.utf8String}"
}
```

Once again, note that we were able to transform an `HttpResponse` to a `ByteString` and print out the result without using Await.  Instead we used `map`, `flatMap`, and `foreach` to accomplish the task.

One mental trick I used when first using Futures was to imagine a Future as a special kind of Array.  You can't select the element out of the Array, which is what Await does, but you can use map and flatMap on the special Array when you want to operate on the element.

Comment: Thank you for your help! But there is a little error in your code: `toStrict` only accept a `FiniteDuration` as a parameter, so `Duration.Inf` will cause a type mismatch. Change it to `1 seconds` and import `import scala.concurrent.duration._` will fix it.

Comment: I have one more problem: what's the best practice to set the timeout?

Comment: @HuangYuheng You are welcome.  I have amended the answer with a finite duration.  In general there is no "best practice" for the timeout.  I usually shoot for a time that would retrieve the body 99.9% of the time, which is dependent on the service you are querying.  Happy hacking.

Answer (score 3):

Akka http is based on akka streams for many reasons, one that can help you understand what is happening here is the following: what if the computer on which your code is running only has 64Gb of RAM, and the size of the HTTP response is 784Tb i.e., much much more than what could fit in your ram + swap? A streaming solution is the only way to get around this, and that's what akka http is excellent at!

So in your case, when the `responseFuture` completes, basically it means only the headers of the http response are available, not the content. Remember, the content can be huge, take hours to download but you can still expect the `responseFuture` to complete in less than a second.

What you call content of the response is called the http entity. Akka http offers it as a stream, but for cases like yours, you can call `.toStrict` on the entity to get it as an (future of) array of bytes rather than a stream.

Finally it is almost never right to use `Await`. You should rather take action when the future completes, by either using `.onComplete`/`.onSuccess`/`.onFailure` or mapping the result to something, possibly combining with other futures using `.map` and/or `.flatMap`.